# How to discover the sum of each day of a month in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, monthcalendar

Lets suppose we have a table (for example `sales`) with three fields `id` (int, primary), `price` (double), `date` (datetime).

How can we get the sum of the `price` attribute to each day of the current month?

And to the last month?

I need a return with something similar too:

**February**

```
01        02        03        04        ...        30
101.1     233.43    1232.42  3232.21             121.23
```

**April**

```
01        02        03        04        ...        30        31
11.1     23.43      122.42   332.21              121.23    2323.32
```

How could we perform this?

Please give me a SQL as example.

I thinking to write a method to discover the number of days of the month and than create the SQL iteratively, but I think this isn't the best way.

Comment: `select sum(price) ... group by year(datefield), month(datefield), day(datefield)`

Comment: You want the result to be horizontal?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, be horizontal isn't really needed, thx for notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting all ideas (thx @MarcB, @Stephan, @GordonLinoff) the SQL bellows is what I'm looking for:

**February**

```
SELECT
    SUM(price) AS daySum
FROM
    sales
WHERE
    date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
GROUP BY
    YEAR(date),
    MONTH(date),
    DAY(date)
```

**April** (we are currently at April month)

```
SELECT
    SUM(price) AS daySum
FROM
    sales
WHERE
    date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
GROUP BY
    YEAR(date),
    MONTH(date),
    DAY(date)
```

Thx a lot.

Comment: Great thanks ! Do you know how you can make it so even for the dates where there is no order, it shows 0. Right now it will just get rid of that day in the result and give inconsistent results (Some days will be missing)

Answer (score 2):

You actually want to do a pivot:

```
select year(date), month(date),
       sum(case when day(date) = 1 then price end) as price_01,
       sum(case when day(date) = 2 then price end) as price_02,
       . . .
       sum(case when day(date) = 31 then price end) as price_31
from sales
group by month(date), year(date)
```

Then add a `where` clause for the dates that you want.  Something like:

```
where month(date) = month(now())
```